# How to add an extra field to the dataset in Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite

My data set is an array of the following form:

```
[
  { "DATE" : "2020-01-02", "COUNTRY" : "Spain", "COUNT" : 110 },
  { ... },
  { ... }
]
```

There are multiple countries and multiple days. There are no gaps in dates.

I want to inject field `DAYS_PASSED` (and subsequently use it for the X axis)
using the following algorithm:

1. Check the value of `DAYS_PASSED` for the previous day for the same country
   and assign it to variable `TEMP`. (If the previous day does not exist, assume 0);
2. Calculate `DAYS_PASSED` using the following formula:

```
   if TEMP > 0, then DAYS_PASSED = TEMP + 1
   else-if COUNT > 100 then DAYS_PASSED = 1
   else DAYS_PASSED = 0
```

So far I have done this in a preprocessing step (outside of Vega-Lite) but I was
wondering if it was possible to migrate the calculation to Vega-Lite, maybe
by plugging-in in a JavaScript function somehow?

I would also like to be able to expose 100 (from the `COUNT > 100` condition) in the
graph so that the user can tweak it to, say, 200.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a series of transforms; for example:

```
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum.DATE)", "as": "date"},
    {"calculate": "datum.COUNT < 100", "as": "pre100"},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "pre100", "as": "offset"}],
      "groupby": ["COUNTRY"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "count", "as": "daysPassed"}],
      "groupby": ["COUNTRY"],
      "sort": [{"field": "date"}]
    },
    {"calculate": "max(0, datum.daysPassed - datum.offset)", "as": "daysPassed"}
  ],
```

Here is a more full example showing this for a small dataset ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJACICCAKgKJmQBMADNwLQ-8OkADRQAwgHkAqgDkmAJQCa7AMoAHWAEsAdiPHS5ZAKxcAvsKrVajVu258BXAMx7Ik2QuWpI6rbtFuBkxkAOxmFtQ09Mxs3vZcgvwALK7uckqqGjqpQWQAjHnhlhjWMXY8CY5GOR4Z3r7ZAWnBqHkm5sVRNrFQ8YlcAGw16V5QDf76HmTcRZFo0bZxFf1CTUF1UACSiLgAnsMtYACcs5Gli73Lji5rtaOQ23j7t4atXKdWCz2cVxzJBxsHjtnpNXmA8kkPiUvuUHH8uNUXp52I89gd8icOnNzt8+o4hkjAaiQYEpqgOO1igBdKhYqDwABOsG0xAAZgB7BkAWzIlE+AGM8Pz8LgEIR2PB2XQxQAKODwfBcgB03QAlK5YKRvPLxXSooLcMLRfBxdqEIqlc0wAAecHvDVaqBqBmEQpcSB6tCdKAAK3ZOlgAHNAy7A2LebR2Wp2MRFa5WZpCLhoOxna77QFNex2azWcRCPAPVSIpFICH2fg1AAjfaocikkaQGnUT3oUsAdx00HZ7YjkCj7H5Fe0hczjpgsF2xAACpr8ynTMXvWWGRXq7WKA3kUu5pBiJzC3XaAmkymzSai8VW5ADUbw94ubAAB4yriieUWuBT2fEedgXhgB+yo5nmBbqmO7BfjOc6EAuVA7lAQ7aIKh4UMUbbUJAj4MgA1uwuA6OKJaYYQyHstAOiBmQGGlk+1GQCeybsN0rjwLsaimvShBcmonJ4B6xGlhux6Jkx3jNKx7GcZAACO+DMvAmiIIpWC6oJmFDrgnL0YxZ6gsiARsRx7DaOyXIBrgHreqYV6CTRmDYXh3gEdoRHLoyzJspyPJHgxmi4CaDKQeaypQT+f4AHxgO6i7qVApFDhR2hUag9kYJAdGpX5p7Bd+MEpoZUnsHJClKQgmiqQJ3qYMJ2VifpknGd4JUjmVKlqdViHslpQVZbp7DNBkhVNVApnmdo-E2XMU0YDNNKmEAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"DATE": "2020-02-02", "COUNTRY": "Spain", "COUNT": 50},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-03", "COUNTRY": "Spain", "COUNT": 70},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-04", "COUNTRY": "Spain", "COUNT": 110},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-05", "COUNTRY": "Spain", "COUNT": 150},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-06", "COUNTRY": "Spain", "COUNT": 200},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-02", "COUNTRY": "Italy", "COUNT": 90},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-03", "COUNTRY": "Italy", "COUNT": 100},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-04", "COUNTRY": "Italy", "COUNT": 140},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-05", "COUNTRY": "Italy", "COUNT": 190},
      {"DATE": "2020-02-06", "COUNTRY": "Italy", "COUNT": 250}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum.DATE)", "as": "date"},
    {"calculate": "datum.COUNT < 100", "as": "pre100"},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "pre100", "as": "offset"}],
      "groupby": ["COUNTRY"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "count", "as": "daysPassed"}],
      "groupby": ["COUNTRY"],
      "sort": [{"field": "date"}]
    },
    {"calculate": "max(0, datum.daysPassed - datum.offset)", "as": "daysPassed"}
  ],
  "concat": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DATE", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "COUNT", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "COUNTRY", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.daysPassed > 0"}],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "daysPassed", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "COUNT", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "COUNTRY", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I am really impressed. I did not realise that those transformation were so powerful!

But.. I am not sure the example in the editor does exactly what I wanted. When I change the last data point for Spain and decrease `COUNT` from 200 to 20, the line on the second graph becomes shorter as if there were only two `daysPassed` for Spain. The way I intended it is a little different. You go along the dates, once you find a data point for a given country that matches the condition (e.g. `value > 100`), then the `daysPassed` counter starts increasing for a given country (and never stops)

Comment: Agreed - my solution assumes momotonic increase. What ideas do you have to extend the solution?

Comment: I accepted the answer; while it does something slightly different it gave enough hints so that I was able to achieve what I wanted. The key was calculating a flag-like field in each data point and then figuring out how window functions worked. I have played with Vega for two evenings and I am blown away by how powerful it is.

Comment: Ideas for improvement (taking your graph as the starting point):

1) assuming there are way more countries - show a list and allow selecting countries to be displayed in the graph
2) callouts on mouse over showing additional data for a data point
3) after hovering over a country, show a daily bar chart for this country on a separate graph (my graph now shows counts per million; the bar char would show absolute numbers)

Comment: I guess I now need to figure out how selections work.  It is sometimes easy to get lost, despite excellent documentation. As an example -  after reading the `datetime` spec (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/datetime.html) I generated those objects in a data preprocessing step (outside of Vega-lite). I did not Vega-lite provided function `toDate()` until I checked your example.